# ArrayList Add Causing Contents to Become Duplicates

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I am trying to create a basic 2d game engine and when I try to load from a save the ArrayList that stores the tiles ends up full of duplicates of the last tile it had added to it.

```
public IWorld loadWorld(Save save){
    FileInputStream in = save.getWorldInput();
    this.init();
    try {
        while(in.available() > 0){
            int id = FileUtil.readInt(in);
            System.out.println(TileRegistry.getTile(save.getTileName(id)).load(in, this));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    generated = true;
    for (Layer layer : getLayers()){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(layer.getTiles().toArray(new ITile[layer.getTiles().size()])));
    }
    return this;
}
```

addTile declaration:

```
public void addTile(ITile tile){
    layers[tile.getLayer()].add(tile);
}
```

add Declaration

```
private List<ITile> tiles = new ArrayList<ITile>();

public void add(ITile tile){
    tiles.add(0, tile);
}
```

addTile is used here

```
public ITile load(FileInputStream in, World world) {
    this.world = world;
    x = FileUtil.readInt(in);
    y = FileUtil.readInt(in);
    loadAdditionalData(in, world);
    world.addTile(this);
    return this;
}
```

You can find the console output here - http://pastebin.com/zfqF9upp

Comment: How are you calling `addTile(ITile)`?

Comment: Clear the list before you load the save game?

Comment: Just a remark, using an ArrayList for adding elements at the head is not a good idea complexity-wise

Comment: And when do you call that? Basically, every time you pass `this` it's one instance. Where do you call `new`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TileRegistry.getTile(save.getTileName(id))` is apparently returning the same one `ITile` object every time you call it, which you repeatedly load with different values, and then add another reference to it to the list.

Make sure your `TileRegistry` is providing distinct `ITile` objects. It would help to explain if you show the place(s) you are calling `new ITile()`.

P.S. `tiles.add(0, tile);` is slow on an `ArrayList` because every time you add an element at the beginning it has to move all subsequent elements along by one position. Adding the element at the end (`tiles.add(tile)`) would be faster; or, use a `LinkedList`, which is not faster generally, but can add elements at the beginning efficiently.